# 517 jpg to unique pdf

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have several jpg(517) and I want to convert to unique  PDF file.
I tried to use "convert *.jpg newfile.pdf"  but the system kill. I think no have memory enough. This is possible to do with some algorithm?
Thanks and sorry my english

Answer (score 1):

The command "convert *.jpg newfile.pdf" will have all images overwrite eachother on the newfile buffer; which, can result in memory allocation errors.

#### One unique PDF with all images

If your trying to create a single PDF file containing all jpg photos, use Imagemagick's `montage` command

```bash
montage *.jpg -tile 2x -geometry +2+2 newfile.pdf
```

Where `geometry` sets the spacing of each image, and `tile` sets layout. Examples at [ImageMagick Montage Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/).

#### One unique PDF for each image

If your trying to create a single pdf for each images, use the `%d` symbol in you destination file name. This will create 517 PDF files containing an individual image.

```bash
convert *.jpg newfile_%d.pdf
```